# python subprocess wildcard is selection only first file

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to delete all the below files:

```
20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_08
20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_04  20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_09
20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_05  20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_10
```

In Linux I simply do:

```
rm 20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_*
```

But when I am doing the same using python script. It is just deleting first file matching the pattern but not all of them:

```
temp = subprocess.Popen('rm 20200922_051424_00011_v4wzh_db508ed0-b8b9-488b-a796-773d1fb4045c_*', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why its not working and also what should I do?

Complete python function is:

```
def remove(filename):
    try:
        cmd = 'rm ' + filename
        print(cmd)
        temp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = temp.communicate()
        if stderr:
            print('Error while running rm command.')
        print("Result of running rm command: ", stdout)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this

Comment: Can you try `cmd = "bash -c 'rm " + filename + "'"` ? Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in python, why not remove them directly from python rather than calling a shell command?

```
for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
  os.remove(filename)
```

Documentation:

- [`os.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)
- [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, I know this. But, it is just one of the use case we have to use something like this with other commands also.

Comment: Generally, using `shell=True` is a bad idea; expand the glob in Python and use `shell=False`?